# How do you pass an array through a PHP web server URL?

Tags: php, ios, objective-c

I'm trying to send data to a PHP web server.

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"xxxxx.com/dbfuncts.php?action=createuser&user=%@&pword=%@&fname=%@&lname=%@&email=%@[&team_id=team_id]", [newPerson objectForKey:@"ua_username"], [newPerson objectForKey:@"ua_password"], [newPerson objectForKey:@"ua_fname"],[newPerson objectForKey:@"ua_lname"], [newPerson objectForKey:@"ua_email"], @@@@@];
//The array goes where '@@@@@' is.
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSData* jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSError *error;
id userProfile = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];


if(userProfile != nil){
    NSLog(@"%@", userProfile);
    return userProfile;
} else{
    NSLog(@"ERROR");
    return nil;
}
```

The only issue is that I don't know how to pass the data in the array in the url. How do I do that?

Comment: You shouldn't use a GET request for this. The plain password will be logged in server logs, etc. Use a POST request and send the data in the payload.

Comment: What method do you recommend? I'm not sure where to look because googling it came up with many different answers.

Answer (score 1):

For that case you should use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-2.0-Migration-Guide) library

You just set your array into json in parameters section, that' all magic.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
NSDictionary *params = @{@"width": width, @"weight": weight};
[manager POST:@"https://mysite.com/myobject" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

To block the execution of the main thread until the operation completes, you could do [operation waitUntilFinished] after it's added to the operation queue. In this case, you wouldn't need the return in the block; setting the __block variable would be enough. So you wrap request in dedicated method and after calling them do waitUntilFinished. But i think, that making Network synchronously isn't good idea.

The entire time your request loads, it will appear that your application has frozen—totally unresponsive to touch and system events until the request finishes.

At the very least, show a loading modal that doesn't dismiss until the request finishes. Even better, make it so a user can interact the app normally while the request is loading, if possible.

***EDIT***

If you need to show something until network is working, so you need to make next steps. First of all wrap your networkMethod:

```
- (void)postEventsWithHandler:(void (^)(BOOL isSuccess))handler
{   
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    NSDictionary *params = @{@"width": width, @"weight": weight};
    [manager POST:@"https://mysite.com/myobject" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    handler(YES);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    Handler(NO)
    }];
}
```

And then you need to call this method from your class, in that case let's imagine, that we have NetworkClass with all network requests.

```
// SHOW modal popup or hud (BMProgressHUD for example)
[NetworkClass postEventsWithHandlerWithHandler:^(BOOL isSuccess) {
    // dismiss modal popup
    // make something...
    if (isSuccess)
    {

    }
    else
    {

    }
}];
```

Comment: I actually used AFNetworking before, but it runs asynchronously and I need it to run synchronously.

Comment: Hmm....okay. That makes sense. The only problem I had with the Asynchronous task was that testing the data didn't work. How would you get a view controller(loading screen) to wait for the background thread to finish?